# XML Special Character Handling

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

VB / C# im attempting to parse the XML file which contains the special character,

```
replace & with &amp
' with &apos
< with &lt
> with &gt
```

the string replace did not as it replaces the special character '<' , '>' in the the tags.
i tried with catch XML exceptions that didn't work when there are multiple special characters in same line, it works if only one special character in a line.
the MS builtin method SecurityElement.Escape didn't work, this has to be done before the XML tags are attached.

im using this file to load a SQL table.

Any other solution to handle the XML multiple special characters?

Comment: You have to manually handle all of the special characters that comes  in between the text.

Comment: Are you trying to manually parse XML? Why not load the XML document into an XDocument or XmlDocument instance?

Comment: Could you show xml example which you think contains special characters?

Answer (score 1):

use System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape 
eg : string XmlFriendly = System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape("the bad ' string");

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `XmlTextReader`? It should handle all that escaping.

Comment: i think for XMLTextreader will given an error if the special characters are not parsed, but im using this to load a SQL table.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you are not trying to process an XML file, you are trying to process a non-XML file which would be an XML file if the special characters were correctly escaped.

So the question is, where does this non-XML file come from? Because the best way to fix it is to fix the process that created it. Creating bad XML and then repairing it is much more difficult than creating good XML in the first place.

Comment: Michael you are correct the file is non xml file would be an xml if special characters are removed, i'm trying to figure out the easiest and fastest way to handle these specail characters