# What to replace with special character < in the xml file

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I found that we can replace `&lt;` with the `<` but it is not working. Is there any other character I need to replace with `<`

I replaced `&` with the `&amp;` and it is working fine.

I am facing problem in my following element tag.

```
<city>north<eastcity</city>
```

Comment: What is the error message you are receiving?

Comment: If you replace the < with &lt; it results in valid xml: <city>north&lt;eastcity</city>. Can you check that?

Comment: what do you mean by "but it is not working"? maybe your XML parser have the problem. any way `<city>north&lt;eastcity</city>` should work.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**

```
 String newText = System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(rawText);
```

**See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityelement.escape.aspx) for more details on this. Hope this helps.**

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

> `<`

with

> `&amp;lt;`

and

> `>`

with

> `&amp;gt;`

Comment: Can you share a code sample of the things you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to replace those chars?

Serialization/Deserialization of XML handles that for you. You can use `XmlTextReader` As for special chars, check existing answers on stack:
[XML Special Character Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229524/xml-special-character-handling)

Comment: I want to parse xml file and for parsing a xml file it must be well formed. This is why i am replacing special chars.

Answer (score 0):

you have to replace

```
<
```

by

```
&lt;
```

(and not the reverse).

Please have a look at XML definition (such as wikipedia page) to know about escaping facilities.

Comment: It should. Maybe your schema (XSD or whatever) doesn't allow the < character in the field.